# Sparkcsv fails to parse date fields

Tags: date, parsing, jdbc, apache-spark, spark-csv

I have a csv file I'm trying to load into spark using sparkcsv. There is a field that has date type values in the format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" (e.g. "2014-09-18 00:00:00") and I wish to designate it as a DateType. However I keep getting

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:140)`

From what I've read this happens when it encounters a string that doesn't follow the default pattern. But mine does! And I even tried adding `option("dateFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")` when reading the csv, but that didn't do anything.

I have read elsewhere that it's possible for this error to occur if the field is empty, however this doesn't seem to be the case.

Also `option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")` doesn't help - same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this with spark-csv_2.10 version 1.3.1.  I then updated to version 1.4.0 and the problem does not appear.

```
@Test
public void fixedInNextRelease() throws Exception {

    List<StructField> structFields = new ArrayList<>();
    structFields.add(new StructField("date_field", DataTypes.DateType, true, Metadata.empty()));
    StructType schema = new StructType(structFields.toArray(new StructField[0]));

    HashMap<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("path", "src/test/resources/date-test.csv");
    options.put("header", "false");
    options.put("delimiter", "|");
    options.put("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s");

    DataFrame left = hiveContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", schema, options);
    assertEquals("2014-09-18", left.first().mkString());
}
```